# Java: Regular expression to read .dat files having syntax - 40_*_p.dat

Tags: java, regex, java-8, camel-ftp

I am getting 17 types of file having following format:

```
85_*_p.dat
88_*_p.dat
32_*_p.dat
40_*_p.dat
41_*_p.dat
70_*_p.dat
22_*_p.dat
23_*_p.dat
46_*_p.dat
24_*_p.dat
25_*_p.dat
26_*_p.dat
52_*_p.dat
123_*_p.dat
28_*_p.dat
29_*_p.dat
35_*_p.dat
```

Where * is any GUID like "40_20200313_0cd6963f-bf5b-4eb0-b310-255a23ed778e_p.dat". The numbers like 85, 88 etc. are interface no. Underscores as well as "_p.dat" is common for all files.

How to write a regular expression which includes all of above files?

Tried but not worked:

```
/[22][23][24][25][26][28][29][32][35][40][41][46][52][70][85][88][123]_(?:.*)_p.dat/
```

Also tried:

```
\d[22|23|24|25|26|28|29|32|35|40|41|46|52|70|85|88|123]_(?:.*)_p.dat
```

This is errorneous as if i add 123 then it also picks 23

Also tried:

```
(22|23|123)_(?:.*)_p.dat
```

It is giving two results with normal and group 1

Not sure how to manage this

Note: Apache Camel has facility to read SFTP File through Regular Expressions. I wanted to create regular expressions for all above files. But need the same for Java.

Comment: @Matt: 
The one i tried is following: /[22][23][24][25][26][28][29][32][35][40][41][46][52][70][85][88][123]_(?:.*)_p.dat/ . updated the same in description too

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is not correct. This regular expression matches all of your filenames:

```
[0-9]+_[0-9a-z_-]+_p\.dat
```

I'll pull it apart and explain.

`[0-9]+` matches one or more digits, the number at the start of each filename (i.e. `22`). You could make it more specific like you have in your example and match `(22|23|24)` which reads like `22` or `23` or `24`.

`_` matches the underscore

`[0-9a-z_-]+` matches the "GUID" part, which can be one or more numbers, lower case letters, underscores and hyphens

`_p\.dat` matches an underscore, the letter `p`, a period (notice that this is escaped with a `\` because `.` is a special regular expression character) and the `dat` suffix at the end

I use [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vdO7ei/1) to play around with regular expressions, give it a go, it has a nice help section too.

Answer (score 0):

You could match 1 or more digits with a repeated pattern that starts with matching either `-` or `_` to prevent matching consecutive `__--`

```
^\d+_[a-f0-9]+(?:[_-][a-f0-9]+)+_p\.dat$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+_` Match 1+ digits and match `_`
- `[a-f0-9]+` Match 1+ times a-f or 0-9
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[_-][a-f0-9]+` Match either `_` or `-` and 1+ times a-f or 0-9
- `)+` Close non capture group and repeat 1+ times
- `_p\.dat` Match `_p.dat`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9PkaQD/1)

**Note** that in Java you have to double escape the backslash:

```
String regex = "^\\d+_[a-f0-9]+(?:[_-][a-f0-9]+)+_p\\.dat$";
```

---

To match those numbers exactly you could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in combination with [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to match the numbers and shorten the pattern a bit:

```
^(?:2[2-689]|3[25]|4[016]|52|70|8[58]|123)_[a-f0-9]+(?:[_-][a-f0-9]+)+_p\.dat$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MS0C2d/1)